# How to label/tag TikZ diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, labels

I would like to be create diagrams using TikZ that have a number on the side of the page (like the `equation` environment makes) that I can label using `\label` and cross-reference using `\ref`.

Essentially, I am looking for something like `\tag` that works inside the `tikzpicture` environment.

For a concrete example, I would like to create something like the first two diagrams on the following page.
[image]

Does anyone know how this can be done in TikZ specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put everything you like into the `equation` environment. Like this, it will behave like an equation which seems to be what you want.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document} 
\setcounter{page}{15}
\noindent
into a commutative diagramm 
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        B\times_A C \arrow{r}{\pi_2}\arrow{d}[swap]{\pi_1} & C\arrow{d}{g} \\
        B \arrow{r}[swap]{f} & A;
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\blindtext

In a general category $C$, one says that a commutative square
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        P \arrow{r}{q}\arrow{d}[swap]{p} & C\arrow{d}{g} \\
        B \arrow{r}[swap]{f} & A
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you which to have the last diagram as well:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        X\arrow{drr}{\gamma}\arrow[dashed]{dr}[near end]{!\delta}\arrow{ddr}[swap]{\beta} & & \\[1ex]
        & P \arrow{r}{q}\arrow{d}[swap]{p} & C\arrow{d}{g} \\
        & B \arrow{r}[swap]{f} & A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe I never tried sticking a TikZ environment inside `equation`...

Comment: @ArtemMavrin Glad to hear that. Sometimes, things are that clear that one can oversee them... :-)

Comment: Can the equation label be on the left hand side?

Comment: @alper off topic here but it should be `\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}`