# How can I have (a) (b) signs at the leftmost side of multiple tikz figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, numbering

I want to have following example format for two tikz figures, where `(a)` and `(b)` are located at most left side of them.

Example reference: Cormen/Introduction to Algorithms 2022 page: 341

[image]

Please note that I am only interested for placing `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, ... labels.

---

The solution I come up with is using  [How to label/tag TikZ diagrams?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267040/how-to-label-tag-tikz-diagrams). But here I was not able to change equation numbers `(2)` to `(a)` and `(3)` to `(b)` , also I was not able to change their location to the most left hand side.

my tex code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{15}
\noindent

\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        x = 5 * 5; \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
into a commutative diagramm
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        B\times_A C \arrow{r}{\pi_2}\arrow{d}[swap]{\pi_1} & C\arrow{d}{g} \\
        B \arrow{r}[swap]{f} & A;
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[compute/.style={draw,thick,font=\sffamily,
            append after command={
                (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[double=gray!50,double distance=3pt,
                line cap=rect,
                shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt]
                (\tikzlastnode.south east)}}]
        \node[compute] (n1) {Node};
        \node[compute,right=2cm of n1] (n2) {More text};
        \draw[thick,-stealth] (n1) -- (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

wanted output:

[image]

Comment: As I see it this isn't a [tag:tikz-pgf] problem but one about numbering equations? (Unless the numbering should be part of the TikZ picture?) What should happen after (z)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I added numbering, should I remove `tikz-pgf` ? I never thought about what will happen after `z` , at most I thought I will use till `g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you like to obtain the following:

[image]

Using @Andrew Swann [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207458/how-can-i-change-the-position-of-equation-number-locally-if-i-am-not-using-the-a) you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\reqnos
\makeatother
\newcounter{eqtn}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{15}

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\begingroup\leqnos
\setcounter{eqtn}{\theequation}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand\theequation{\alph{equation}}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        x = 5 * 5; \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
into a commutative diagramm
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        B\times_A C \arrow{r}{\pi_2}\arrow{d}[swap]{\pi_1} & C\arrow{d}{g} \\
        B \arrow{r}[swap]{f} & A;
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[compute/.style={draw,thick,font=\sffamily,
            append after command={
                (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[double=gray!50,double distance=3pt,
                line cap=rect,
                shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt]
                (\tikzlastnode.south east)}}]
        \node[compute] (n1) {Node};
        \node[compute,right=2cm of n1] (n2) {More text};
        \draw[thick,-stealth] (n1) -- (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\setcounter{equation}{\theeqtn}
    \endgroup
\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I wonder, why you not use the `sidcap` package and use for example as

```
\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A figure and its caption framed}
\label{fig:test}
\end{SCfigure}
```

and for them change caption numbering on the similar way as is done above.

**Edit:**
Simpler code with manual tagging of equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\reqnos
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{15}

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begingroup\leqnos
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        x = 5 * 5;  \tag{a}\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
into a commutative diagramm
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        B\times_A C \arrow{r}{\pi_2}\arrow{d}[swap]{\pi_1} & C\arrow{d}{g} \\
        B \arrow{r}[swap]{f} & A;
    \end{tikzcd}      \tag{b}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[compute/.style={draw,thick,font=\sffamily,
            append after command={
                (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[double=gray!50,double distance=3pt,
                line cap=rect,
                shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt]
                (\tikzlastnode.south east)}}]
        \node[compute] (n1) {Node};
        \node[compute,right=2cm of n1] (n2) {More text};
        \draw[thick,-stealth] (n1) -- (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}     \tag{a}
\end{equation}
    \endgroup
\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Compilation result is the same as before.

Comment: Mostly yes, just after the `into a commutative diagramm` line can it start with `(a)` again?

Comment: Try to reset `equation`number. Or even simpler, in equation insert numbers manually. I will show this ASAP.

Comment: I had not idea `sidcap` existed , if it provides simplier solution I can switch to using that, since in some other cases may end up using `(a)` `(b)` bottom of the tikz-image

Comment: Is it possible to show tag leftmost middle , like here instead it shows up at bottom leftmost : https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/87c3799313d5de5a8a44473d2e429c3f?permalink_comment_id=4329524#gistcomment-4329524

Comment: @alper, yes it is possible. Just add to `tikzpicture` option `baseline=(current bounding box.center),`.

Comment: Inside the `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` we also align tikzfigure to rightmost instead of keeping it centered?

Comment: @alper,  sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you have new problem, please ask new question, where with an MWE show your problem.

Comment: @alper, sory, this site is not a forum bit question/answer site. Please (again) ask new question qith your new problem.

Comment: / okay sorry ...