# How can I align tikzfigure to rightmost side if its inside an equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tag

My main goal is to have tags at leftmost of tikzfigures. When I define the `tikzfigure` inside the equation it is centered where collised with the tag. Since there is space on the right-hand side how can I shift tikzfigure to righthand side to prevent its collision with the tag. Note that I am working on a double-column.

tex code (original code is take from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661116/127048)

> ```tex
> \documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
> \usepackage{lipsum}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \makeatletter
> \newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
> \newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
> \reqnos
> \makeatother
> \usepackage{tikz-cd}
> \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
> \begin{document}
> \setcounter{page}{15}
> \begingroup\leqnos
> \lipsum[1][1-3]
> \begin{equation}
>   \begin{tikzcd}
>       B\times_A
>   \end{tikzcd}~\tag{a}
> \end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation}
>   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),compute/.style={draw,thick,font=\sffamily,
>           append after command={
>               (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[double=gray!50,double distance=3pt,
>               line cap=rect,
>               shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt]
>               (\tikzlastnode.south east)}}]
>       \node[compute] (n1) {Node};
>       \node[compute,right=2cm of n1, yshift=11mm] (n2) {More text};
>       \node[compute,right=2.2cm of n2] (n3) {More};
>       \node[compute,below=2cm of n2] (n4) {text};
>       \draw[thick,-stealth] (n1) -- (n2) -- (n3) -- (n4);
>   \end{tikzpicture}~\tag{b}
> \end{equation}
>   \endgroup
> \end{document}
> ```

output:

[image]

Here if the tikz figure shifted to the right, its collision with the tag will be prevented.

Related: [How can I have (a) (b) signs at the leftmost side of multiple tikz figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661116/127048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are to wide that can be fit in one column width. There in the case, that images had to be placed in one column, is beside

- reducing font size to `\small` or even to `\footnotesie`,
- reducing width of nodes with allowing multi lines text in them,
- reducing horizontal distances between modes,

not much possibilities to what can be done. An example how aforementioned can be implemented is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\reqnos
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begingroup\leqnos
\begin{equation}
   \begin{tikzcd}
       B\times_A
   \end{tikzcd}~\tag{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
 node distance = 13mm,
compute/.style = {draw, thick, font=\small\sffamily, align=center,
                  append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
                    (\LN.south west) edge[double=gray!50,double distance=3pt,
                                          line cap=rect,
                                          shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt]
                    (\LN.south east)}},
                        ]
    \node[compute] (n1) {Node};
    \node[compute,right=of n1] (n2) {More text};
    \node[compute,right=of n2] (n3) {More text text\\ text text text};
    \node[compute,below=of n2] (n4) {text};
    \draw[thick,draw, -Stealth, shorten > = 3pt, shorten < = 3pt]
        (n1) edge (n2)
        (n2) edge (n3)
        (n3) to (n4);
   \end{tikzpicture}~\tag{b}
\end{equation}
   \endgroup
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
From comment follows:

- in you approach is not possible to obtain what you after
- one way is to define new environment, which has )not referable) tag on the left, and images or other text on the right, centered  or raggedleft.
- example of sucn command can be:

```
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand\LST[3]{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[c, font=\bfseries] X[#1] @{}} }
    #2  &   #3  
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}}
```

- In use of above definition you need to a wee bit to redefine `compute` node style:

```
compute/.style = {draw, thick, font=\small\sffamily, align=center,
                  append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
                    ([xshift=-2pt] \LN.south west) 
                        edge[double=gray!50,double distance=3pt,
                                          line cap=rect]
                    ([xshift=+2pt] \LN.south east)}},
                        ]
```

- An exampe, how to use aforementioned, is:

```
\documentclass[journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand\LST[3]{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[c, font=\bfseries] X[#1] @{}} }
    #2  &   #3  
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[label font=bf, labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\LST{c}{(a)}{$B\times_A$}
\LST{r}{(b)}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
 node distance = 12mm,
compute/.style = {draw, thick, font=\small\sffamily, align=center,
                  append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
                    ([xshift=-2pt] \LN.south west) 
                        edge[double=gray!50,double distance=3pt,
                                          line cap=rect]
                    ([xshift=+2pt] \LN.south east)}},
                        ]
    \node[compute] (n1) {Node};
    \node[compute,right=of n1] (n2) {More text};
    \node[compute,right=of n2] (n3) {More text text\\ text text text};
    \node[compute,below=of n2] (n4) {text};
    \draw[thick,draw, -Stealth, shorten > = 3pt, shorten < = 3pt]
        (n1) edge (n2)
        (n2) edge (n3)
        (n3) to (n4);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
        } 
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Sorry, due to (github) server error I cant upload image produce with above MWE.

Comment: What if I have a very packed figure where I couldn't reduce the width between nodes, can I shift it sligthly to the right (instead of keeping it centered) if it has an empty space at right most side? basically I want to aligh the figure to the right while having (a) (b) ... notations at the leftside

Comment: What you like to get with your approach, is not possible. See addendum to answer, if it offer what you after.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want more space between 'tag (b)' and the flow chart. But I have no problem with your MWE. Maybe just because of the page margin setting? See the attachment below:
[image]

Please comment with more details about what you want if I guessed wrong.

Comment: I was working on a double-column

Comment: @alper, this is not reflected in your MWE. It show, that you have one column article. Please, clarify your question and adequate correct your MWE.

Comment: @Zarko I updated my question corresponding to double-column, thanks for the heads up.